# How do I set session variable in ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

How do I set a session variable in ASP so it restricts content from displaying based on age? I have declared the Dim variable but it's still not being picked up therefore not returning the correct result. See my code below:

```
<html>
<body>
<%
Dim Age

Age = datediff("yyyy"),dob,date)

<%if session("Benefitclass") = "Gold" and age < 50 then%>
Your defined benefits have been emailed.
<%end if%>

%>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: If someone answered your question you mark one as the answer. Please do so for all of your questions, people appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra set of <% %> tags, give this a shot:

```
<html>

<body>
<%
Dim Age

Age = datediff("yyyy",dob,date)

if session("Benefitclass") = "Gold" and age < 50 then
    Response.Write "Your defined benefits have been emailed."
end if

%>
<body>
</html>
```

also, you have the variable "date" listed in your dateDiff() function. date is a reserved keyword i believe in vbscript, if you're trying to get the current date/time, use Now() instead:

```
Age = datediff("yyyy",dob,Now)
```